# Simple start use Doctrine2 mongoDB ODM

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-orm, php-mongodb, doctrine-odm

I wanna start use of mongoDB via Doctrine2, I installed MongoDB and working!
(Windows8 64bit, PHP 5.4, Xampp, NetBeans7.2)

but my problem:

I downloaded Doctrine 2 mongoDB ODM from https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm and read document here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html but i cant setup doctrine 2 yet! :(

i'm not workin via big freamworks (ZF or Sym), usually use light MVC pattern!

can anyone create (or show me how to start use that!) **simple project** that work with one object like users via Doctrine 2 MongoDB ODM?